# what is fs:[register+value] meaning in assembly?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

```
xor    ebx,ebx
mov    eax,DWORD PTR fs:[ebx+0x3]
```

I know first line of this code, but what's `fs:[ebx+0x3]`?
and why it giving me an error while compiling ?

```
test.asm:2: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
```

Comment: In x86, the colon means "concatenate". So, it would concatenate fs with [ebx+0x3]. But what is fs in this context? Seems strange and that we're definitely missing something.

Comment: It's code written for MASM, not NASM. It's also code that doesn't appear like it would do anything useful under Windows. Why are you trying to assemble this code?

Comment: IIRC, the NASM syntax for this is `dword [fs:ebx+0x3]`.  Zeroing `ebx` looks like it's done to save a byte of code-size.  `[fs: 0x3]` would require a 4 byte displacement encoding of the `mov` instruction.  `xor` takes 2 bytes, and allows the `mov` to use a `[fs: reg + byte 0x3]` encoding.  So the `mov` is 3 bytes shorter, at the cost of an extra `xor` (and hopefully the zeroed `ebx` is needed later anyway, so it's actually a 3B saving.)

Answer (score 10):

The `xor` opcode sets EBX to 0. So the `mov` opcode accesses a DWORD at fs:[3]. This accesses the last byte of the [Win32 Thread Information Block's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block#Accessing_the_TIB) `Current Structured Exception Handling (SEH) frame` located from `fs:[0]` to `fs:[3]` (4 bytes) and the first three bytes of the `Stack Base` variable, the initial value of ESP.

Unless you are confronted with some sophisticatedly constructed and obfuscated virus or anti-debugging-technique which combines these 3+1 bytes to something useful, this would just be a somewhat *random number*.

Another possibility is, that the "segment" register FS has been modified prior to these instructions to contain a sensible base address. In that case, this may be an useful instruction like many others. It is undecidable by the code snippet you provided.

For example

```
mov eax, fs
inc eax
mov fs, eax
...
xor    ebx,ebx
mov    eax,DWORD PTR fs:[ebx+0x3]
```

would return the 'Stack Base' in EAX - '(FS+1)+(0+3)' = real-FS:[4] = 'Stack Base' location.

Addition: *For completeness: why it doesn't assemble has been mentioned in the comments by 'Ross Ridge': It's MASM syntax and not NASM syntax.*